# Constructing Injective Maps with Disjoint Images

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have to construct $m$ injective maps, $\mathbb{F}=\{f_0,f_1,f_2,\ldots f_{m-1}\}$ from $\mathbb{W_n}=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ to $\mathbb{W_{mn}}=\{0,1,2,\ldots,mn-1\}$ such that $\forall i,j\in\mathbb{N}$ where $i,j\leq m$ and $i\neq j,\;f_{i}\left(\mathbb{W_n}\right)\cap f_{j}\left(\mathbb{W_n}\right)=\emptyset$. That is, I need $m$ different injective maps whose images are all disjoint.

One such example is,$$\mathbb{F}=\{f_i\mid f_i(x)=mx+i\},\;0\leq i\lt m.$$
But here, the mapping is very straightforward and easily predictable, even to a person who has not been exposed to the function. I'm hoping I'd get some help in constructing these sort of maps, but in a less intuitive way using, say, modular arithmetic and such.

Comment: Welcome to MSE..+1 upvote for your formating and for sharing your thoughts